# TypError when save function of Pillow called. Too many arguments

Tags: python, qr-code, python-imaging-library

Attempting to call the save function results in a TypeError. As a side note: qrcode requires the importing of PIL as PilImage.

It's also worth mentioning that I did not have this error when using the Python Imaging Library. It only occurred after switching (by recommendation) to Pillow.

```
from qrcode import *
import PIL as  PilImage
from PIL import Image
import qrcode
qr = qrcode.QRCode (
    version = 1,
    error_correction = qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L,
    box_size = 10,
    border = 2
)
qr.add_data('Hello World')
qr.make(fit=True)
img = qr.make_image()
img.format = 'PNG'
img.save('test.png')

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#70>", line 1, in <module>
    img.save('test.png')
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\qrcode\image\pil.py", line 29, in save
    self._img.save(stream, kind)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1467, in save
    save_handler(self, fp, filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\PngImagePlugin.py", line 605, in _save
    ImageFile._save(im, _idat(fp, chunk), [("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageFile.py", line 452, in _save
    e = Image._getencoder(im.mode, e, a, im.encoderconfig)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 395, in _getencoder
    return encoder(mode, *args + extra)
TypeError: function takes at most 4 arguments (6 given)
```

Comment: "As a side note: qrcode requires the importing of PIL as PilImage." - I don't think so. A library usually does not depend on imports in your code.

Comment: Yes, sorry. After some further reading I believe that you're right.

Answer (score 1):

As a last stitch effort I did a re-install of the Pillow module. This miraculously solved my problem and `img.save()` now works exactly as intended. I'm not sure how, but something must've gone awry during initial installation. Thank you for all of your help, though. This experience has been hell. If you'd like to know what this conflict was in pursuit of here is my git-repository: https://github.com/NamesJ/qr-tickets

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that `img.size()` returns a tupe of length 4?

In this case you should make it return a tuple of length 2 like this:

```
size = img.size
img.size = size[0], size[1]
img.save('test.png')
```

Have a try and report back. It could be that there are other possibilities.

Comment: When I attempted to use `size = img.size()` I received the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    size = img.size()
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable`

Comment: edited. I am referring to this line:  `[("zip", (0,0)+im.size, 0, rawmode)])`. It seems it could generate 2 more arguments than necessairy.